# Try/catch block inside method

Tags: java, android

I have a class and I have a method inside this class.

Method:

```
public void login(String username,String password) throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException {
    ConnectionConfiguration configuration=new ConnectionConfiguration("", 5222,"localhost");
    configuration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
    connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
    try {
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(username,password);
        ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        chatmanager.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
            public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, final boolean createdLocally) {
                chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
            }
        });
    }                       
    catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Xmpp requires try/catch block.I defined try/catch inside method.But when I try to use this method in main class I am getting compiler error :

```
Unhandled exception type IOException
```

I am using like this:

```
SmackClass smack=new SmackClass();
smack.login("asdad","asdasd");
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMPPException, SmackException, IOException`

Remove these from the throws clause of the `login` method.

They cause the compile-time error in the main class.

In general, don't declare to throw those exceptions
which you already handle in the method itself.

Comment: If I want to declare throws clause of the login method,how should be my code ?

Comment: @Okan In that case you should have a try-catch block in the calling method (which is the main method in your case, I guess).  `try { login(); } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {...}`. And also, don't catch these exception within `login` itself. Just let the calling method handle them.

Comment: You mean catch these exception in main class ?

Comment: @Okan Yes, you said that's what you want basically.

Comment: @Okan And you have one more option here: in `login`, you can catch them but re-throw them e.g. `catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); throw e;}` In that case, you still have to use `try-catch` in the main method. But this doesn't make much sense in your case (just from a logical standpoint).

Comment: Which method you suggest ?

Comment: @Okan Well, it all depends on what you want. All these are legal options, and one can use them based on where he can best handle the exceptions. If in login - then catch them there. If login cannot handle them - just propagate the exceptions to the calling method. Even the main method in Java can declare to throw the exceptions (if even main cannot handle them).

Answer (score 1):

Your method shouldn't declare `throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException`, if you already handled it inside the `login` method.

Comment: "handle" is a big word... I don't really view `printStackTrace()` as "handling" an exception :p

Comment: If he catches it, he handles it, what he does with it is a completely other problem

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solution

1. Get rid of throws exception from the method
2. Get rid of try and catch inside the method and use it in main like
   below:

:

```
 public static void main(string[] args){
try {
SmackClass smack=new SmackClass();
smack.login("asdad","asdasd");
}
catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You are not handling the exception since your method can throw it